# AngularJS wrapper for p5.js - p5 directive and service

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I wrote an [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) wrapper for [p5.js](https://github.com/lmccart/p5.js) called angular-p5:

```
angular.module('angular-p5', [])
.service('p5', ['$window', function($window) {
  return $window.p5;
}])
.directive('p5', ['p5', function(p5) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      sketch: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var sketchObj = null;

      var destroySketch = function() {
        if(!sketchObj) {
          return;
        }
        sketchObj.remove();
        sketchObj = null;
      };

      scope.$watch('sketch', function(sketch, oldSketch) {
        if(oldSketch) {
          destroySketch();
        }
        if(sketch) {
          sketchObj = new p5(sketch, element[0]);
        }
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', destroySketch);
    }
  };
}]);
```

View the repository for [angular-p5.js here on GitHub](https://github.com/wxactly/angular-p5.js).

I have a bunch of questions... And I'm open to any and all feedback about anything I didn't mention. Hit me with your best shot!

1. Naming convention - is the module name okay, or should I just name it "p5"? Or something else? Is it accepted practice for a wrapper like this to be called "angular-*", or is that considered redundant?
2. Is it weird to have a service and a directive with the same name? It seemed to make sense to me, since you can inject `p5` into a controller or include `<p5>` in your template. And it seems to work... but is this sort of thing common?
3. Does it cause any issues for `sketch` to be a function reference? (See: [`$scope.mySketch](https://github.com/wxactly/angular-p5.js/blob/master/example/example.js).) This is a requirement of the p5 api. Again, this seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is common...
4. Did I handle all the cases I need to handle for observing and cleaning up the bound sketch data? Does it look like I cleaned it up properly on change and destroy?
5. Is using `link` exclusively appropriate for this implementation, or should I try to factor this into a directive controller?

Also I graciously welcome any feedback about the project itself... It's fairly lightweight at the moment. Anything on GitHub is fair game if someone wants to take a look - docs, examples, etc.

Comment: Also this is obviously my first post... please let me know if I should break this question up into a few smaller, focused questions... I can't tell if this large bullet-list is a good format for this site.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, I hope you get some good answers!